# I need to know a method to determine if a file is open in exclusive mode or otherwise (read-write etc.)?

Tags: delphi, file-io

I have a backup application and was using Zipmaster component until now wherein Excel/Word files even if open would get Compressed but PST files would be skipped.
In other words files that are exclusively locked by other processes are skipped. My new compression tool halts with an error upon encountering exclusively locked file. So I want to trap and skip the exclusively open files. Delphi's Assignfile etc all give same message for files open in Excel/Word or PST.

I need to know a method to determine if a file is opened by other processes in exclusive mode or otherwise (read-write etc.) ?

Kinly note: I can't use Volume Shadow Copy on some Drives eg: Fat32

Regards

Comment: If it is so you can open the file when not in use, handle the exception and/or error. Using such functions in the answers is a really bad idea, since the file might be opened in between checking and your subsequent attempt to open it. The only reason for using such answers would be if you don't actually intend opening the file, but are using the result for information purposes only

Comment: You need to fix the compression tool itself - checking the file before hand just adds a race condition as a file could be opened exclusively between when you check and when the component accesses the file to compress it.

Comment: I changed my answer so you could use improved code than before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [CreateFile function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) to test file for accessing from your thread.

What Docs said:

> Creates or opens a file or I/O device. <..> The function returns a handle that can be used to access the file or device for various types of I/O depending on the file or device and the flags and attributes specified.

Let's write some code:

```
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileName: String;
  FileHandle: THandle;
  Flags: Cardinal;
  LastError: Cardinal;
  TextErrorCode: PChar;

  procedure DisplayNotification;
  begin
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER or 
                  FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 
                  nil, LastError, LANG_USER_DEFAULT, 
                  @TextErrorCode, 0, nil
                 );
    ShowMessage(TextErrorCode);
    LocalFree(HLOCAL(TextErrorCode));
  end;

begin
  FileName := 'YourPath + YourFileName';
  Flags := GetFileAttributes(PChar(FileName));
  if Flags <> INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES then
    begin
      if (faDirectory and Flags) <> faDirectory then
        begin
          FileHandle := CreateFile(PChar(FileName),
                                   GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,
                                   nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0
                                  );
          LastError := GetLastError;
          try
            if FileHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
              begin
                // Execute you backup code
              end;
          finally
            CloseHandle(FileHandle);
          end;

          // Notify user about problems with opening the file
          if FileHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
            DisplayNotification;
        end
      else
        // Notification about specified filename defines a directory not a single file
    end
  else
    begin
      // Notify user if there is a problem with getting file's attributes
      LastError := GetLastError;
      DisplayNotification;
    end;
end;
```

Now you can check if file is taken by another process and if it is not then do your code to backup opened file.

Useful links:

1. [GetFileAttributes function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesa)
2. [FormatMessage function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage)

Comment: This code is a race condition. The file can get opened by someone else after you have checked access but before you can open it for backup. Once you open the file, use it! You are leaking `FileHandle` if `FileOpen()` succeeds, you need to call `FileClose()`. Use `fmShareDenyNone` (or at least `fsShareDenyWrite`) instead of `fmShareExclusive`, you don't need exclusive rights just to read from the file. An app can block read access without using exclusive access, if `FileOpen()` fails, the error code will be `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` if the requested access was blocked by another open handle.

Comment: .. and don't release the (read) handle until you backup the file. Then there won't be any race.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz That would fall under the "*Once you open the file, use it!*" portion of my previous comment.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I really missed to release file's handle. Thank you. I read some articles on `msdn` network, and think there is no need to use share flags at all. Also I have made some tests and there is no access to opened file (at least with `TFileStream`). Code in answer changed.

Comment: My problem persists. Using code given by Dima and options given by Remy I tested on Notepad file, Excel , PST. With fmShareDenyWrite I get Excel and PST not opened with LastError = 32. What I am looking for is different messages for Excel and PST. With fmShareDenyNone all opened.

Comment: @Aura, LastError = 32 means `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`. Do you use my *modified* code? If file is opened by Excel and you are trying to pen it using my code then variable `Opened` will remain false, because LastError will be `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`.

Comment: @Aure, wait a minute. Do you want achieve *files that are exclusively locked by other processes are skipped* or you want to open file *while* it is opened by another process?

Comment: @Dima if you don't use any sharing flags at all, you end up opening the file for exclusive access, which fails if the file is already open for *any* reason. If you use more flexible sharing flags then you can open the file for reading if someone else has the file open as long as they opened the file with read sharing allowed. `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` means you tried to open the file with a flag that is not compatible with someone else's flags. For instance, if they are writing and you don't allow writing, or you want to read and they don't allow reading

Comment: `...
  FileHandle := System.SysUtils.FileOpen(FileName, fmShareDenyNone );  // tried all fm...
  try
    LastError := GetLastError;
    memo1.lines.add(Filename+' '+IntToStr(LastError)+' '+IntToStr(FileHandle))
   finally
...
`
`...
begin
  openfiles('F:\test.xlsx') ;
  openfiles('F:\test.txt') ;
  openfiles('F:\test.pst') ;
  openfiles('F:\test.docx') ;
end;`

`Output

`F:\test.xlsx  32 4294967295`
`F:\test.txt  0 320`
`F:\test.pst  32 4294967295`
`F:\test.docx  32 4294967295`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thank you for your patience and detailed description of how share-xxx flags work. I've added `fmShareDenyWrite` flag to my answer - now another process could read but not write data from\to file.

Comment: @Dima the new code is still pretty bad. The `FileExists` is unnecessary, creating another race condition. Just call `FileOpen` unconditionally and let it fail if it needs to. If the file does not exist, the error code will tell you that. Also your handling of `LastError` and `Opened` is just plain wrong. If the file fails to open, `FileOpen` will return -1 and you can use `GetLastError` to find out why. Otherwise, if the file opens successfully, `FileOpen` will return something other than -1 and you should not call `GetLastError` at all

Comment: @Dima try this instead: `FileHandle := FileOpen(...); if FileHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then begin try {backup code} finally FileClose(FileHandle); end; end else begin LastError := GetLastError; {error handling} end;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, why `FileOpen` will return -1, if it must return (as said in Emb. help) `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, which defined in `Windows.pas` as `THandle(-1)`? I modified code to get rid off `FileExists` function and now check file's attributes to decide if this is a file and if so do some actions.

Comment: you shouldn't really be calling GetLastError unless GetFileAttributes fails.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, what is wrong with using `GetLastError` along with `GetFileAttributes`? `Docs` documentation says nothing about it.

Comment: Docs say you can call GetLastError when the function *fails*, not when it succeeds.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I don't see nothing bad to call `GetLastError` even if call to `GetFileAttributes` function was successfull. Besides, I obtained error code *not for* `GetFileAttributes` function but for `CreateFile` to get extended information about open operation. Anyway I changed the code to also provide feedback for user on its native language if any error has been occured.

Comment: This is better not only because you don't call GetLastError when *CreateFile* (sorry about that) does not fail, but also because you don't try to provide an exhaustive list of all possible errors (I can imagine `GetLastError` returning `ERROR_BAD_NETPATH` or `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED` or who knows what else). BTW, you can use `SysErrorMessage` to format the error string. That will also help with the memory leak (allocated and not freed for TextErrorCode).

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, yes you are right: it is a silly mistake to not free resources. Changed. `SysErrorMessage` is a better approach to display error description, but as long as I use `WinAPI` to know if a file can be opened to read, I will use `FormatMessage` function. Just for self-learning)

Comment: Nice work, I appreciate the effort you've put in this answer.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz thank you. If I make mistakes I always try to solve them.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use..

```
function IsFileInUse(FileName: TFileName): Boolean;
var
  HFileRes: HFILE;
begin
  result := False;
  if not FileExists(FileName) then exit;
   HFileRes := CreateFile(PChar(FileName), GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE, 0, nil, 
OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
   result := (HFileRes = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
   if not result then CloseHandle(HFileRes);
end;
```

Comment: You don't need `FileExists` function here, because you already check file existence by setting `OPEN_EXISTING` flag. Also check for `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, `ERROR_INVALID_NAME`, `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` which could be returned by `GetLastError`.

Comment: @Dima there are several more error codes that could be returned by `GetLastError` if the file is not found. In my own code, I check for like half a dozen error codes. To the point where it makes me wonder if checking for access errors (access denied, sharing violation) would be easier than checking for non-existance

Comment: @RemyLebeau, main point of my comment was if one uses Windows API to open file then what gain is there from using VCL's  `FileExists`?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications.  FileExists removed.